# Java Image Colorprofile Issue

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

I resize my images via imageio but images which use the Color profile 
`sRGB IEC61966-2.1- IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space` turn out green-ish:

Source Image:

[image: Source Image]

Output Image:

[image: Output Image]

The strange thing is that it seems that imageio is somehow breaking during runtime. A restart of my JVM somehow cures the issue and it does not happen for a while. Other images which don't use this special Colorprofile resize just fine.

I'm running JDK 1.8.0_25 and use the following image jars:

- jai_imageio-1.1.jar
- jmage-0.7-2.jar
- image4j-0.7.jar
- jai_codec-1.1.3.jar
- jai_core-1.1.3.jar

Has someone maybe encountered this issue before?

Comment: Please add an MCVE that exposes the problem. I wrote a small sample program that resampled the image and stored it without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample code that works for me. I'm using a slightly more updated Java version.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
```

Source code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));

    BufferedImageOp op = new AffineTransformOp(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1.43, 1.43), AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC);
    Rectangle bounds = op.getBounds2D(image).getBounds();
    // NOTE: Passing null as last param to filter() works fine, but creates a destination 
    // image (TYPE_INT_ARGB) that JPEGImageWriter will write in a way other software 
    // interprets as CMYK rather than ARGB. It does not look like your result image, though... 
    // And, it works fine if you write the image as PNG, even if passing null.
    BufferedImage result = op.filter(image, new BufferedImage(bounds.width, bounds.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR));

    ImageIO.write(result, "PNG", new File("foo.png")); 
    ImageIO.write(result, "JPEG", new File("foo.jpg"));
}
```

The resulting `foo.jpg` looks like this:

[image]